# Why is this assignment involving wildcards legal in Java?

Tags: java, generics, types, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

Most questions about wildcards want to know why something sensible is rejected by the compiler. My question is the opposite. Why is the following program accepted by the compiler?

```
void test(List<? extends Number> g1, List<? extends Number> g2)
{
    g1 = g2;
}
```

I tried to explain this from the Java Language Specification, but I have not found the answer. I had the impression from various descriptions of Java generics and wildcards that each use of a wildcard is captured as a completely new type, but apparently not here. I have not found any nasty behavior that follows from this assignment being allowed, but it still seems "wrong".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I face these questions, I approach this in a slightly different manner.

First of all, every single `wildcard` is `captured`, `everywhere`, by `javac`. In plain english: every time `javac` "sees" a `wildcard` it is going to transform that (this is *almost* accurate as you will see further). Specifically, let's say we have this:

```
List<? extends Number> list;
```

`javac` will transform to:

```
List<X1> list
```

where `X1 <: Number`, where `<:` means it is a *subtype of*, as such : `X1 is an unknown type that extends Number`. This will happen for every single occurrence. And it might be very weird, at first, in some scenarios:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<?> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    one(l);
    two(l, l); // fails
}

public static <T> void one(List<T> single){

}

public static <T> void two(List<T> left, List<T> right){

}
```

*capture conversion* was applied individually to each `List`, it's like this happened:

```
two(List<X1>, List<X2>)
```

---

Now to why is your example accepted, is far more interesting, imho. You know that *capture conversion* is applied, but according to the `JLS` it is [not applied everywhere](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6):

> If the expression name is a variable that appears "on the left hand side", its type is not subject to capture conversion.

It's like saying that only *values* are capture converted, not *variables*.

So in this case:

```
g1 = g2;
```

`g1` has not been capture converted, while `g2` has. It's like doing:

```
List<? extends Number> g1 = List<X1> (g2) // pseudo-code
```

We know that `X1 <: Number` so, as such `List<X1>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`, so the assignment works.

Even if you change `? extends Number` to `?` (this is not a bounded wildcard anymore), this would still work.

Comment: Very interesting. It seems then that capture conversion is mandatory in some contexts, unlike other conversions that are applied as needed. The JLS is not very clear on this point.

Answer (score 3):

`List<? extends Number>` is best read as:

**This is a list of numbers, but, covariantly.**

In other words, this is a list of some concrete but unknown type. However, I do know that, whatever type it might be, at least it is either Number or some subclass thereof.

Generics is weird; once you opt into some variance, you get the restrictions to go along with that. In the case of collections, 'covariance' comes with the baggage of 'no adding'.

Try it.

`g1.add(XXX);`

the only thing that is legal for `XXX` here? `null`. That's literally it. The full and complete and exhaustive list of all you can add to this thing. certainly `Number x = 5; g1.add(x);` is not going to be allowed by javac here.

By writing `List<? extends a thingie>` you're saying: Yeah, I want that. I'm signing up to this restriction that I get to add absolutely nothing (other than the academic case of literal `null`). In trade for handcuffing yourself, the things you can pass in for `g1` is expanded considerably.

You can also opt into contravariance:

```
void foo(List<? super Integer> list) {
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(5)); // works!
    Integer x = list.get(0); // no go
}
```

contravariance is the opposite. add works. get doesn't work. Which in this case means: The type of the expression `list.get(0)` is just.. `Object`.

---

Now that we've covered that:

```
void test(List<? extends Number> g1, List<? extends Number> g2) {}
```

means 'my first parameter is a list of numbers, but I opt into covariance handcuffs', and 'my second parameter is a list of numbers, but I also opt into covariance handcuffs for this one too', it now makes sense why java lets you write `g1 = g2`. g2 is guaranteed to be an `X<Y>`, where X some concrete subclass of `List`, and Y is either `Number` or some subclass thereof.

This is 100% compatible, type-wise, with the notion of 'some sort of list whose type param is some covariant take on Number'. The only thing you can do a `List<? extends Number>` is to invoke methods of List where any T in the signatures are 'disabled' for parameters, and replaced by the bound (`Number)` for return types.

That's.. exactly what `List<? extends Number>` is describing, so it's compatible.

Comment: tl;dr the assignment is valid, but you get restrictions downstream.

Comment: imho, this is entirely correct theory, but misses the question itself. this has to do with _capture conversion_ and how it is (and is not) applied to _variables_ and _values_.

Comment: @Eugene well, it explains the reasons behind capture conversion. The aim is, once you understand the logic behind what the generics means, you can use that to 'guess' what java's language spec says and get it right pretty much every time. It's either that or memorize the entire JLS :P

Comment: @rzwitserloot I see your point, thx for the follow-up.

Answer (score 3):

"I had the impression from various descriptions of Java generics and wildcards that each use of a wildcard is captured as a completely new type, "

That statement is correct.

So what? You are confusing the type of the object with the type of the variable.

Consider this code:

```
String s = "abc";
Object o = s;
```

o has type Object which is assignment compatible with the type of s. But that doesn't mean String and Object are the same type.  No different with your example. You have two different List types for the objects, but one type for the variables. Each variable has type List<? extends Number>, so the assignment is fine. When you make the assignment, the object's generic type is List<x> for some completely new unknown type x. But the variable type remains List<? extends Number>.

Comment: this _is_ the correct answer to the question. a fat 1+. I've also added the [JLS part that backs this up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63962748/1059372)

Answer (score 0):

How could it *not* be valid?

Both variables have identical type (in this case `List<? extends Number>`), so the compiler *must* allow assignment of one to the other.

---

The objects assigned to the variables may have different types, but the *variable* types are identical, so assignment is always legal.

The compiler does not know or care what the *actual* type of an object assigned to a variable is, even if it can be determined from the code. It cares only about *declared* types when checking types.

Comment: but these are not identical types, every single wildcard (be that bounded or not) is _different_ from each other, the reason is [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63962748/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene Incorrect: the *objects* may be different types, but the *variable* types are identical, so assignment is always legal. The compiler does not know or care what the *actual* type of an object assigned to a variable is, even if it can be determined from the code. It cares only about *declared* types.

Comment: @Eugene's explanation is correct. Follow his link to the JLS, or try assigning the list to an Integer variable and see what the error message says. The type of the RHS is a capture type, which is assignable to but not the same as the variable type on the LHS.