# Generic Casting Issue

Tags: java, generics

I have defined a generic interface that has a supplier and a consumer:

```
public interface ItemProcessor<T> {
    processItem(T task);
    T getNextItem();
}
```

However, I am running into issues when using this interface:

```
List<ItemProcessor<?>> itemProcessors = new ArrayList<>();

// add itemProcessors to list

for (ItemProcessor<?> itemProcessor : itemProcessors) {
    itemProcessor.processItem(itemProcessor.getNextItem());
}
```

This give me the compile error `Required type: capture of ?, Provided type: capture of ?` Since I'm using the same item processor object, shouldn't java be able to infer that the type is the same?

Comment: No it shouldn't, thats why it gives you the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack this a bit, via a so called "wildcard capture method":

```
private static <T> void process(ItemProcessor<T> item) {
    item.processItem(item.getNextItem());
}
```

And then change your call to:

```
for (ItemProcessor<?> itemProcessor : itemProcessors) {
    process(itemProcessor);
}
```

I have two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716920/cant-add-value-to-the-java-collection-with-wildcard-generic-type/56934197#56934197) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63947339/why-is-this-assignment-involving-wildcards-legal-in-java/63962748#63962748), for example explaining why this happens. But there is also [the official Oracle tutorial explaining things](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html)